# How to show that$(X,d)$ is totally bounded

Tags: metric-spaces

How to show that a metric space $(X,d)$ is totally bounded $\iff$ every infinite subsets of $X$ contains distinct points which distinct points that arbitrarily close to each other.

I don't know how to prove $\Leftarrow.$ Please help.

**BTW I'm looking for a little hint !**

Comment: $X$ is totally bounded iff any sequence(net) in it has a Cauchy subsequence(subnet).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\langle X,d\rangle$ is not totally bounded. Then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all finite $F\subseteq X$, $\{B(x,\epsilon):x\in F\}$ does not cover $X$, i.e., $X\setminus\bigcup_{x\in F}B(x,\epsilon)\ne\varnothing$. This implies that we can recursively construct a set $A=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\subseteq X$ such that

$$x_{n+1}\in X\setminus\bigcup_{k\le n}B(x_k,\epsilon)$$

for each $n\in\Bbb N$. $A$ is an infinite subset of $X$; does it contain distinct points that are arbitrarily close to each other?

Comment: A is infinite? is it because there are infinitely many finite F? also, could you please your conclusion remark?

Comment: @user104078: $A$ is infinite because the map $n\mapsto x_n$ is an injection: if $n>m$, $x_n\notin B(x_m,\epsilon)$, so $x_n\ne x_m$. In fact, $d(x_n,x_m)\ge\ldots\;$ what?

Comment: \epsilon. so the contrapositive is proved.

Comment: @user104078: Exactly right.